# Possible to rake db:schema:load without wiping the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have been mucking with my development database and am getting ready to move it to production.  I made some edits outside of rails, so I don't have a migration for all of my changes.  I know I can `rake db:schema:dump` to generate a schema.rb file, but can I apply that to an already populated production db without wiping the data? Something similar to `rake db:schema:load` without wiping the data?

If not, do I just need to manually create the migrations that would catch the production db up?  If I do make those migrations, won't all future calls to `rake db:migrate` on the dev box fail because the change in the migration already exists in the dev db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `rake db:schema:load` is that it will forcefully create the tables, which you can see in `db/schema.rb`:

```
create_table :users, :force => true do |t|
  # etc
end
```

What I would recommend is that you do create the missing migrations. You can fix your local dev database by adding the timestamps to the `schema_migrations` table manually. That is the consequence of changing your schema by hand.

I personally always make sure that `rake db:migrate:reset` (drop all tables and migrate from scratch) will produce the same `db/schema.rb` as `rake db:schema:dump` would. Any change in the database schema must be automated by a migration. You could even make it part of your CI script, by running `rake db:migrate:reset` and than asserting that `db/schema.rb` didn't change from what is in source control.

Comment: How do I do the step: "fix your local dev database by adding the timestamps to the schema_migrations table manually"?

Comment: When you add a migration, it starts with a timestamp, like `db/migrate/201204131212_create_users.rb`. These timestamps are stored  in the `schema_migrations` table. Just add them with your favorite tool for mucking about in the database.

Comment: So if I add the timestamp to the `schema_migrations` table and then run `db:migrate`, that migration won't be run?

Comment: Also, try running `rake db:migrate:status` to see which Migrations have run, and which have not.